# Not getting second activity even after Commiting shared preferences instance in Another activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In MainActivity i tested whether App is started for 1st time or not. 
If yes then start Activity OneTime else SecondActivity.

```
 public static final String MyPreferences = "MyPrefs";
 public static final String Country_Name = "countryKey";
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sharedPreferences = 
    getSharedPreferences(MyPreferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("My_Pref",true))
    {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,OneTime.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
 }
```

In OneTime activity I have a simple form with like enter CountryName and then I changed My_Pref instance like below.

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
 TextView country;
 Button save;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.one_time);
    country = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
 }
 public void savepref(View view) {
    sharedPreferences =  PreferenceManager.
 getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String text1 = country.getText().toString();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("countryKey",text1);
    editor.putBoolean("My_Pref",false);
    editor.apply();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
 }
```

But Even after this When app starts again it goes to OneTime activity instead of SecondActivity. I searched problems like this but I failed to get sort this out.
I am new to Shared preference concept. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not using the same shared preference.

in one place your use this

```
getSharedPreferences(MyPreferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

then in another place you use this

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
```

pick one or the other and stick with it

Comment: I changed the PreferenceManager to getSharedPreference and it worked for me.